# SQL Server 2012 getting last row in table with no unique identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a text datatype in a table and want to get the last row.

I use the following SQL and get a correct answer I want to know if REACH 2012-13 is selected from the query because it is the last row in the table or because REACH 2012-13 comes after REACH 2011-12 as a string. Hope this makes sense

Thanks

```
SELECT  TOP 1 [Reach Report]
FROM [REACH Reference]
ORDER BY [Reach Report] DESC
```

and gives me

```
REACH 2012-13
```

The data is:

```
REACH 2009-10
REACH 2010-11
REACH 2011-12
REACH 2012-13
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly do you want to know about `TOP`? Hint: `TOP` has more to do with the explicit ordering you supply via the `ORDER BY` clause than it is related to the data types of the columns in the `SELECT` clause. `TOP` doesn't care at all *what* you `SELECT`; it's only concerned with *how much* you want to `SELECT`.

Comment: So waht is your problem since it gives you the last row that you want??

Comment: @MitchWheat what is the meaning(full form) of your comment?

Comment: Read The Fine Books On Line

Comment: Forget concept of "last row in database" - there is no such thing in SQL (underlaying technical implementation doesn't count). Look at database table as basketful of records - which one is first, which one is last? You have always to use explicit order, especially with TOP keyword. Like 'SELECT TOP .... ORDER BY ....'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a 10,000 ft view:

a string comparison is being done between each `Reach Report` values, and the results of each comparison are used to order the 4 rows (`ORDER BY [Reach Report] DESC`).

```
REACH 2012-13
REACH 2011-12
REACH 2010-11
REACH 2009-10
```

Then, the first one is chosen and returned (`SELECT  TOP 1 [Reach Report]`).

Comment: sorry badly worded question on my behalf. I want to know if REACH 2012-13 is selected from the query because it is the last row in the table or because REACH 2012-13 comes after REACH 2011-12 as a string

Comment: It is selected because it is the first in the ordered result set, as You can see in the example I provided.